# How to center a Highcharts Organization Chart

Tags: typescript, vue.js, highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts' organization chart to display a company's organization hierarchy however, I'm having difficulty centering the chart inside of the highcharts container. It's always right justified by default. How can I center the chart?

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEKLJ.png)

My code:

```
chartOptions = {
title: {
  text: "Organization Chart",
},
chart: {
  type: "organization",
  inverted: true,
},
series: [
  {
    name: "my company",
    keys: ["from", "to"],
    states: {
      hover: {
        brightness: -0.3,
      },
    },
    data: this.projectData.organizationSchema,
    levels: [
      {
        level: 0,
        color: "#8B93AB",
        dataLabels: {
          color: "black",
        },
        height: 25,
      },
      {
        level: 1,
        color: "#8B93AB",
        dataLabels: {
          color: "black",
        },
        height: 25,
      },
      {
        level: 2,
        color: "#0267B0",
      },
      {
        level: 4,
        color: "#0267B0",
      },
    ],
    nodes: this.projectData.organizationNodes,
    colorByPoint: false,
    color: "#007ad0",
    dataLabels: {
      color: "white",
    },
    borderColor: "white",
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
],
```

};

Comment: Probably a CSS issue tbh. Do you have a real [repro] with more context, hosted on Codesandbox or alike?

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor?